# Can't change current cursor

Tags: html, css, button, cursor

I am doing a dropdown box, when my mouse hovers over a button it drops the box down and if the box hovers it will display the block but the problem is that I can't seem to change the cursor when the mouse is hovering over the dropdown box. It stays on pointer even though I want to have it on default.

Thank you.

css code:

```
.applesauce{
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: -0%;
  height: -10%;
  margin-top: -70%;
}
.applesauce button{
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: -18%;
  font-size: 200%;
  margin-top: 47%;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: inherit;
  border: none;
  background-color: #3498DB00;
  color: #0d0d0d;
}
.applesauceDropdown button{
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 8%;
  font-size: 110%;
  margin-top: 0%;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: inherit;
  border: none;
  background-color: #3498DB00;
  color: #0d0d0d;
}
.applesauceDropdown{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  right: 23%;
}
.applesauce a{
  color: black;
  font-size: 110%;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
.applesauce button:hover + .applesauceDropdown{
  cursor: default;
  display: block;
}
.applesauce button:hover{
  color: #666666;
}
.applesauceDropdown:hover{
  cursor: default;
  display: block;
}
.applesauceDropdown button:hover{
  color: #666666;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

html code:

```
    <div class="applesauce">
    <button>Applesauce</button>
    <div class="applesauceDropdown">
      <a href="#">applesauce</a>
      <button id="readMore">read more ...</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The applesauceDropdown:hover is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try the snippet. I put the hover on the `<a>` tag and that seems to give the desired result.

The reason the cursor wouldn't change is that you were actually hovering over the `<a>` tag when you hovered over the word "applesauce".

```css
.applesauce button:hover+.applesauceDropdown {
  cursor: default;
  display: block;
}

.applesauce button:hover {
  color: #666666;
}

.applesauceDropdown a:hover {
  cursor: default;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="applesauce">
  <button>Applesauce</button>
  <div class="applesauceDropdown">
    <a href="#">applesauce</a>
    <button id="readMore">read more ...</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It does seem to work on the snippet, but unfortunately, on my page of code, it still seems to have the same problem. The only way which is working for me is if I remove the href, but I would like to keep it unless I have no other choice.

Comment: It seems that something is different in your actual code compared to the example in your question. Can you edit the question to show code that is more representative of your actual code?

Comment: I think I've added everything that could have a potential effect